# MFC - How to display icon in Static Picture Control bigger than 32x32

Tags: mfc

I have a MFC dialog application with a picture control. I add an icon file with different size of images (32x32, 48x48, etc...) into the icon resource. Then I set the following picture control properties:

Type - Icon
Real Size Image - True

I have the following code under OnInitDialog():

```
HICON hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage( AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PONCAD),IMAGE_ICON, 48, 48, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR ); 
m_Icon1.SetIcon( hIcon );
```

The icon did get displayed but the problem is that the icon is cropped off. I think the total display windows is still 32x32. So part of the icon is missing.

How to get the icon displays in size 48x48 properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use DrawIconEx win32 API and it should be called when ever window redrawn/moved or resized.

For more help go through the below link

ms-help://MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/resources/icons/iconreference/iconfunctions/drawiconex.htm